# How to create model objects via ModelForm ForeignKey?

Tags: django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a model for Classroom and Student as shown below

```
class Classroom(models.Model):
    COURSE_NAME = (
        ('MA8', 'Math 8'),
        ('SC10', 'Science 10'),
        ('PH11', 'Physics 11'),
        ('PH12', 'Physics 12'),
    )
    BLOCK_NUMBER = (
        ('11', 'Block 1-1'),
        ('12', 'Block 1-2'),
        ('13', 'Block 1-3'),
        ('14', 'Block 1-4'),
        ('21', 'Block 2-1'),
        ('22', 'Block 2-2'),
        ('23', 'Block 2-3'),
        ('24', 'Block 2-4'),
    )
    class_list = models.TextField()
    course_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=COURSE_NAME)
    course_block = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=BLOCK_NUMBER)


class Student(models.Model):
    classroom = models.ForeignKey(Classroom, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    nickname = models.CharField(default='JohnS', max_length=31)
    attend = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

I created a form for Classroom.`class_list` and TextField is where the user copy/pastes a list of names.  I want to then parse the `class_list` and save each individual name as `nickname`. I first tried the following but this doesn't seem to save the Student objects.

```
forms.py
class ClassroomForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Classroom
        fields = ['course_name', 'course_block','class_list']

views.py
class ClassroomCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Classroom
    form_class = ClassroomForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        classroom = form.save(commit=False)
        s = Student()
        for line in classroom.class_list:
            s.nickname = line
            s.save()
        classroom.save()
        return super(ClassroomCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('classroom:submitted')
```

I also tried creating StudentForm which allows a user to choose `course_name` and `course_block` (which corresponds to a particular `class_list`).  The form or view would then create the individual Student objects and display them.  I read about ModelChoiceField but I can't figure out how to implement this.

How and where do I (auto) create Students objects from a ForeignKey field?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my question with the [help of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35824115/4618992).  Here is the modified code I used for models.py.  My view is just a standard CreateView from the ModelForm.

```
class Classroom(models.Model):
    ...  dictionary stuff ..
    class_list = models.TextField()
    course_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=COURSE_NAME)
    course_block = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=BLOCK_NUMBER)
    group_size = models.IntegerField(default=3)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.get_course_block_display()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):  
        super(Classroom, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        # overrides the default save function to parse the class list
        studentList = []
        studentList = self.class_list.split('\n')
        for line in studentList:
            line = line.strip('\r')
            s = Student.objects.create(nickname = line, classroom = self)
```